Focal lens for exact 3D printing?
I can't understand how focal lenses work in Blender, and in general. I sculpt only for 3D printing. My first attemps where made with a 50mm lens in the viewport, but some people told me that that kind of lens maybe was distorting a bit the view, so my sculpts looked a bit exxagerated, specially the ones that looked for realism.
After a bit of research, I decided to use an 85mm lens in the viewport. I think I'm more confortable with that lense, the problem is that today I noticed that other 3d software, like for example, Chitubox, doesn't render in the exact same focal lens, and I'm worried to pour hours into a sculpt just to print something that is not exact. The difference is not a lot, but a bit noticeable, being that the Blender one is a bit more "flat".
So, which lens should I use in Blender? My goal is that the 3D print is EXACT to what I see and sculpt in the Blender viewport. 85mm or 50mm?
TLDR; See bold text above.
Examples: Blender view (grey one, 85mm) and chitubox (blue one).



Human eye focal distance is roughly equivalent to 22mm lens, maybe closer to that value you get closer to expected results

85 mm gets used because in portrait photography this is a commonly used lens, so looking at a sculpt with a 85 mm lens might look similar to how portraits of people look. The 22 mm which @DuarteFarrajotaRamos mentions (I've read 17 mm elsewhere as well) is the physical focal length of our eye, but this is most likely not very practical for sculpting, because you have to get a lot closer to sculpt fine details and with that short focal length, distortions will be very strong.

The view angle of the main sharp and colored human vision is around 40° to 60°, which is why a 50 mm lens with 46° degrees is often referred to as "normal" lens. But like all focal lengths, it all depends on viewing distance as well. The problem will always be, when you move around in the viewport, zooming in and out for sculpting, perspective and proportions change. Getting "EXACT" what you see in the viewport depends on how you view it. And since you want to print it and have a real-life object, just take a picture with some other lens and/or distance, and all looks completely different.

And to conclude this: Getting close to someone's nose (with a camera or your eye) will make the nose look very large. But if you sculpt it that large, it is oversized. The only "correct" sculpting would be if you have real-life measurements like how wide is the head, how far is the nose pointing out etc. and then check this in orthographic view if these measurement are correct in your sculpt. Then viewing it with whatever lens from any distance should look like doing the same with a real head of those measurements.
